# How do I create a queue in a header file that will be accessible by all files?

Tags: c++, header, queue

Currently in my header I have the following

```
struct queue{
std::queue<int> queue;
};
```

What I'm trying to do is create a queue data structure that will be accessible from all files. However, I do not want to create a new queue every time I call it, but rather I want to be able to pass this same queue into other functions. Is this possible from using the C++ queue library?

Comment: When you say "pass" the queue, you mean as an argument when calling the function?

Comment: Are you talking about Singleton class/struct?

Comment: @StoryTeller kind of. I'm actually doing the producer consumer problem (I didn't mention this in my initial question because I wanted to keep it straightforward) and my producer function in my `producer.cpp` is of a void type and only takes (void * arg) as the arguments since I call this function with `pthread_create`. Ultimately in this producer function I want to be able to push ints into this queue.

Answer (score -1):

I might be able to help more with a little more code/context about what you're trying to achieve.

You have an object `std::queue <int> Q` which you want to be accessible to multiple ???(files? classes? functions?). You have a few options :

1. Make this object global.
2. Pass a pointer of this object to ??? which will then operate on the object using the given pointer.
3. (Recommended) Pass a reference to this object to ???. This way you'll be able to use it normally and all the ??? will have access to the same object.

Again, if this is not clear, i'll be able to help further after seeing more context. Some more code perhaps?